# Is there way to Install NPM?

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio, npm, azure-webapps

When we run npm i command from VS it throws the below error on Debug file

error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms failed, reason: write EPROTO 40916:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:

We alredy tried below commands still and reinstalled same error

npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

Answer (score 0):

To install node modules we have different approaches based on the project type.

- By running the`npm` command  , a folder with name  `node_modules` will be created with the dependencies.

Check the below steps to Install `npm` Packages in Visual Studio - Node.js Application.

- In `VS` => open `Create a Project` window => click on `Install more tools and features`  and click on `Next`.

[image]

- Visual Studio Installer will be opened.
- Make sure all the options under Node.js are selected, if not select the options and click on `Install while downloading`.

[image]

- Create a `Node.js` Web App.
- Right click on the `npm` folder and select `Install npm Packages`.

[image]

**Install npm Packages** command is similar to running `npm install`.

- Wait for few seconds and click on `Show All Files` icon, you can see a new folder `node_modules` is created and is in hidden mode.
  [image]
- Right click the `node_modules` folder and select Include in Project.
  [image]
- You will get the below warning message.
  [image]
- Even without including the folder in the project we can still use the packages.

***References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/npm-package-management?view=vs-2022#npmInstallWindow)***